# 10gbE on Ubuntu 10.04 LTS Desktop and VirtualBox

Tags: networking, virtualbox

I am aware that there is support for 10gbE on Ubuntu server, but is there also support in desktop version?  I don't see why not, but I would like to confirm before purchasing an expensive NIC.

Second question is, does VirtualBox currently support using host's 10gbE?  I have tried searching around, and it looks like VMWare ESX-i does, but I'm not too certain about VirtualBox.

Thank you!

Comment: Not programming.

Comment: 10/100 gigabit ethernet is supported on virtualbox via bridged accesss to the host network

Answer (score 1):

The issue is really about whether the drivers for your specific 10 GE NIC are included in the desktop kernel.  And as far as I know, there are no Ethernet NIC drivers that are enabled in the server kernel but not in the desktop kernel.  Even if there were, there really wouldn't be any trouble in installing the server kernel on an Ubuntu desktop install and using it.

What specific NIC were you planning to use?

Virtualbox should be able to use a 10 GE interface in the same way as any other Ethernet interface.